# Termius is not connecting to remote server when openvpn3 is used

Tags: openvpn, termius

I am using Ubuntu. I have multiple EC2 servers in AWS. i can connect to those server through VPN and i am using OpenVpn3.

If i connect to openvpn3 through local terminal in ubuntu and then connect to EC2 remote servers in local terminal through SSH, it is working fine.

But then if i connect to openvpn3 thorugh local terminal and then trying to connect to remote server host through termius, termius in not connecting to remote server.

trying to find solution but hard luck that i have not came across any such topic or article or blog on same.

Can anyone help me?